# VBA code to transfer table from txt file to excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a code to read a table in a txt file, and export the first to columns into an excel table. But for some reason I'm running into some errors. It continues to copy the first row which I don't want it to and misses the last row in the table.

Refer to Error 1 and Error 2 for pictures. Error 1 shows the txt file and the table I want to "copy". Error 2 shows how it is importing into excel. As you can see it misses the "9.5" row and copies the "name and dev" row instead

```
  Sub AddNewData()
If ActiveSheet.Name <> "EntryPage" Then GoTo EnterData
Pump_Tag_ID = InputBox("Please Type Pump Tag:", "Enter Pump Tag")
If Pump_Tag_ID = "" Then End
Worksheets("ImplementationSheet").Range("H1") = Pump_Tag_ID
TotalSheets = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If Pump_Tag_ID = Sheet.Name Then
            Sheets(Pump_Tag_ID).Activate
        Else
        i = i + 1
        End If
    Next Sheet
    If i = TotalSheets Then
        Dim Ans As Integer
            Ans = MsgBox("The Pump Tag # does not exist. Please add it.", vbOKCancel + vbInformation)
        Select Case Ans
            Case vbOkay: GoTo Form_AddNewTag
            Case vbCancel: Exit Sub
        End Select
Form_AddNewTag:
        AddNewTag.Show
    End If
If cContinue = "No" Then End
'Get The Data
EnterData:
CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False



Dim myObj As Object
Dim myDirString As String

Set myObj = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With myObj
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & ".domain\Documents"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.txt", 1
    If .Show = False Then MsgBox "Please select TXT file.", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
    myDirString = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
Sheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & myDirString, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
     .Name = "TxtImport"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 1252
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

'rest of the formatting codes here
Range("B1") = "=MATCH(""CSYS:"",A:A,0)"
dDate = Range("C2")
DataStart = Range("B1") + 1
Range(Cells(DataStart, 1), Cells(DataStart + 24, 2)).Copy Worksheets("ImplementationSheet").Range("A1:B25")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    Worksheets("ImplementationSheet").Activate
    Worksheets("ImplementationSheet").Range("A1:B25").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ImplementationSheet").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ImplementationSheet").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Worksheets("ImplementationSheet").Range("A2:A25"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ImplementationSheet").Sort
        .SetRange Worksheets("ImplementationSheet").Range("A2:B25")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Worksheets("ImplementationSheet").Range("A1").Select

Worksheets("ImplementationSheet").Range("F1") = dDate
Worksheets(CurrentSheet).Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
NewOrExistingVolute.Show

End Sub
```

### Error 1

[image: Error 1]

## Error 2

[image: Error 2]

Comment: Are you possibly setting your Copy range too high? Have you tried hard coding the range to see if you get the correct result? I.E. `Range(Cells(DataStart, 1), Cells(DataStart + 24, 2)).Copy` as something like `Range("B2:G10").Copy` or whatever the correct range would be.

Comment: I've tried changing the range but it won't work out. It works on my coworkers computer but for some reason it wont work on mine and we're running the same version and both on windows.

Comment: Maybe try adding `ActiveSheet` before Range, I.E. `ActiveSheet.Range`

Comment: Are you getting an error? On another note, have you tried commenting out ActiveSheet.Delete and checking to see what that sheet looks like? My first guess would be that you need to copy starting one row lower than what you're doing now.

Comment: I will update the code, to include the entire module.

Comment: Is this all the code you have?  Also, do you mind to provide some sample data so I can give it a shot?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if you get a different result:

```
DataStart = Range("B1").Row + 1
```

Comment: What about DataStart = Range("B1").Row + 2...Any way you could include the text data you are using so I can try to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I cant upload the attachments, unless im mistaken